# Access property of parent page in user control

Tags: asp.net

I have a hidden field on my default.aspx page. Within default.aspx page I have a user control which has a label on it. I need the label to display the value on the hidden field. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a public property on the user control which exposes the label text:

```
public string LabelText
{
   get { return this.label1.Text; }
   set { this.label1.Text = value; }
}
```

Then set this from the page code-behind. So if the ASPX for your page has something like this in it:

```
<uc1:UserControl ID="userControl" runat="server" />
```

In the code-behind, you could do

```
this.userControl.LabelText = "something";
```

Doing it this way means that your user control doesn't have to know about the page that's using it. This helps the user control to be re-used on many different pages.

Comment: Thanks. How would I use this on a master page formation? Can I create a class that changes a Div content using this method?   HtmlGenericControl name = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("name"); does not show anything on the class section.

Comment: @Kenyana: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "master page formation". You would probably be better using a `Panel` rather than a div. I'll update my answer a bit...